# Will Natty run without a PC BIOS (i.e. with UEFI)

Tags: 11.04, bios

There are [plans](http://www.rozickas.com/2010/10/17/computers-without-bios-faster-start/#more-13) to remove bios from new computers. Is Natty prepared for this? Will it work when I buy a newer hardware or should I buy older pc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can run any gnu/linux distro without bios(uefi that is) since 2001-2002.

grub-efi

Comment: downvoted because OP wasn't asking about the kernel, but the installer. And as far as I know

Comment: The Natty installer uses BIOS emulation. The only way to actually boot using EFI requires a lot of work. Natty is not prepared for UEFI. http://grub.enbug.org/TestingOnMacbook

Answer (score 3):

The current linux kernel available on Maverick was built with EFI support:

```
grep _EFI /boot/config-2.6.35-24-generic-pae 
CONFIG_EFI=y
CONFIG_FB_EFI=y
CONFIG_EFI_VARS=y
CONFIG_EFI_PARTITION=y
```

If you are buying an PEW if possible please test drive it with a live cd, unless you do an exhaustive support check for each component there are some chances that something will not work as good as you would expect.

Answer (score 3):

Since Kernel 2.6.25 [EFI is supported in all modern Linux distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface) - this also includes 11.04 Natty. You could also have [Coreboot](http://grub.enbug.org/CoreBoot) with GRUB2 payload to boot without a BIOS.